# Concurrency in Pthread

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have a c program running in Linux kernel 2.6.18-194, server has 1 cpu socket with 6 cores with hyper-threading , thread1 receive data and then thread2 and thread3 pass the data thread1 received to another process , after both thread2 and thread3 successfully finish passing data , thread1 will receive data again !!

The floowing is thread1 source :

```
        DoGetDataFromSocket() ;
        iGlbBOOKReadDone = 0 ;
        iGlbPOSIReadDone = 0 ;
        sem_post(sembook) ;
        sem_post(semposi) ;
        sem_wait(semfinished) ;
```

The following is thread2 and thread3 source :

```
    if(bThisThreadIsBook==1)
        sem_wait(sembook) ;
    else
        sem_wait(semposi) ;

    DoPassDatatoAnotherProcess() ;

    if(bThisThreadIsBook==1)
    {
        __sync_add_and_fetch(&iGlbBOOKReadDone,1) ;
    }
    else
    {
        __sync_add_and_fetch(&iGlbPOSIReadDone,1) ;
    }

    Pthread_mutex_lock(&DoneMutex) ;
    if(  (iGlbBOOKReadDone == 1) && (iGlbPOSIReadDone == 1) )
        sem_post(semfinished) ;
    Pthread_mutex_unlock(&DoneMutex) ;
```

It works fine to me , I try to remove mutex_lock DoneMutex in thread2 and thread3 , it still works fine , what I am curious is , if thread2 is  doing __sync_add_and_fetch(&iGlbBOOKReadDone,1) ,  and thread3 is doing __sync_add_and_fetch(&iGlbPOSIReadDone,1)
at exact the same time , then both thread will take if(  (iGlbBOOKReadDone == 1) && (iGlbPOSIReadDone == 1) )  to false , and sem_post(semfinished) would never be called ,
But I do a lot of pressure tests ,this never happen!!  Is it related with __sync_add_and_fetch function ?

Comment: Is it OK for `sem_post(semfinished)` to be called twice (once by each of thread 2 and thread3)?  I assume that double-posting would be a bug - otherwise in the next 'round' Thread1 will think that the other threads have immediately finished processing. That race condition seems to exist even with the mutex operations.  If your stress tests haven't uncovered that bug, then that's an indication that your stress tests aren't adequate, or that the bug only happens extremely rarely (meaning it'll happen at the worst possible time).

Comment: Thanks for your kind replying,since only (iGlbBOOKReadDone == 1) && (iGlbPOSIReadDone == 1) will call sem_post(semfinished) ;
that mean thread2 and thread3 both finishing the action , the sem_post(semfinished) ; will wake up sem_wait(semfinished) ; in thread1 , so thread1 would do DoGetDataFromSocket() ;
so I think each time thread1 get the data, thread1 wake up thread2 and thread3 to do the work and then wait for both of thread2,thread3 finish the work and wake up thread1 again in endless loop ....

Comment: I think with mutex , it should work as I expect , what I don't get is without mutex , it should failed sometimes , but it never fail, if thread2 see iGlbPOSIReadDone = 0 and thread3 see iGlbBOOKReadDone =0 at the same time , then sem_post(semfinished) ;
won't be called , with mutex , this will not happen for sure !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, regardless of whether you use the mutex or not you have a race condition where the `semfinished` semphore can be posted twice, which means that `thread1` might not allow the threads to finish in a future round.

It's easy to see that both `thread2` and `thread3` can simultaneously 'reach' the blank line just before the `pthread_mutex_lock()` call.  If that happens, then both threads will call `sem_post(semfinished)`.

To avoid this situation and to make the code easier to reason about, making it so you can be certain that exactly one of `thread2` and `thread3 will call`sem_post(semfinished)`, you might want to consider doing something like the following:

- thread1:

  ```
  DoGetDataFromSocket() ;
  threadDoneCount = 0;
  sem_post(sembook) ;
  sem_post(semposi) ;
  sem_wait(semfinished) ;
  ```
- thread2 and thread3:

  ```
  if(bThisThreadIsBook==1)
      sem_wait(sembook) ;
  else
      sem_wait(semposi) ;

  DoPassDatatoAnotherProcess() ;

  int doneCount = __sync_add_and_fetch(&threadDoneCount,1) ;

  if (doneCount == 2)
      sem_post(semfinished) ;
  ```

Comment: Thank you,Burr , you are right !!  i have missed something important !!  appreciate for your kindly explanation , it help a lot !!!